# accesing number saved in a vector which holds classes

Tags: c++, class, vector, stl

How can I access number in a class that is in a vector list?

Sketch:

```
class MyClass myClass
{
  public:
    int i = 5;
}


std::vector<MyClass> listOfMyClasses;

myClass myObject;

std::cout << myObject.back().i << std::endl;
```

Comment: I think you have more fundamental issues than accessing a member of a class since your code will not compile as it stands. Have a look here at how to post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access as usual.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class MyClass
{
  public:
    int i = 5;
};

int main(void){
    std::vector<MyClass> listOfMyClasses;

    MyClass myObject;
    listOfMyClasses.push_back(myObject);

    std::cout << listOfMyClasses.back().i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```